# how do tab groups work in ubuntu firefox

Tags: firefox

In ubuntu firefox, when I open a new tab, it does not appear in the bar at the top next to the existing tabs.  Then I can't figure out how to switch between the hidden tab and the visible tabs.  I must be missing something trivial, but I have no clue how to switch tabs.

Comment: Screenshot?, do yo have add ons that may be interfering with that?

Comment: Check and see if Ctrl+Tab work. A hidden tab isn’t standard in Firefox – there should be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

To use Tab Groups, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

I think a video will explain it better: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zU_MMUgEPes

You can also look at:

- http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tab-groups-organize-tabs
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9kR1Os1h1k#t=1m29s